# DatabaseError: ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword when i insert into oracle use python

Tags: python, oracle

When i batch insert into oracle use python like this, it throws the error:

```
DatabaseError: ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
```

and i tried to insert only one row in each loop, it still throws this error.
 in my oracle, i use the sequence to make the column id increase itself, then here i don't insert data to id, i think there is no need to insert value to column id, i don't known whether it's true for this. I need your help, thanks very much!

```js
db = cx_Oracle.connect("*","*","*" ) # 打开数据库连接
    print db
    cursor = db.cursor()  # 使用cursor()方法获取操作游标

    begin=datetime.date(2017,1,1)
    end=datetime.date(2017,1,5)
    result=[]
    for i in range((end-begin).days+1):
        print i
        day=begin+datetime.timedelta(days=i)
        a=(str(day),1,1,day.strftime("%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00"),1,day.strftime("%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00"),0)
        print a
        result.append(a)
    
    print result
    sql = "INSERT INTO calendar(date,type,created_user,created_at,updated_user,updated_at,deleted) VALUES (:1, :2, :3, :4, :5, :6, :7)"
    cursor.prepare(sql)
    cursor.executemany(None,result) #执行SQL语句
```

Comment: please post the structure of the `calendar` table

Comment: what are the values you pass to insert?

Comment: create table "factory_calendar" 
(
   "id"                 number(11)           not null,
   "date"               date,
   "type"               number(11),
   "created_user"       number(11),
   "created_at"         date,
   "updated_user"       number(11),
   "updated_at"         date,
   "deleted"            number(11),
   constraint pk_factory_calendar primary key ("id")
)
@mic4ael

Comment: and this is the data i want to insert: [('2017-01-01', 1, 1, '2017-01-01 00:00:00', 1, '2017-01-01 00:00:00', 0), ('2017-01-02', 1, 1, '2017-01-02 00:00:00', 1, '2017-01-02 00:00:00', 0), ('2017-01-03', 1, 1, '2017-01-03 00:00:00', 1, '2017-01-03 00:00:00', 0), ('2017-01-04', 1, 1, '2017-01-04 00:00:00', 1, '2017-01-04 00:00:00', 0), ('2017-01-05', 1, 1, '2017-01-05 00:00:00', 1, '2017-01-05 00:00:00', 0)]  @user7294900

Answer (score 0):

Based on the structure of your table I can tell the problem lies in lack of value for `id` column in your `INSERT` statement. You are not providing value for your primary key. Your `INSERT` should use for example a sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE sequence_name
START WITH     1
INCREMENT BY   1
NOCACHE
NOCYCLE;

INSERT INTO calendar(id, date,type,created_user,created_at,updated_user,updated_at,deleted) 
VALUES (sequence_name.nextval, :1, :2, :3, :4, :5, :6, :7)
```

Comment: but i will run this in python, when i write create sequence ...in python , it will throw errors.@mic4ael

Comment: you need to create the sequence before running your Python script

Comment: I already create the sequence before, and the table id can increase itself now. then where i did wrong for my python script?@mic4ael

Comment: I think the sequence may can't be used in my python script?

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. There is no auto-incrementing in Oracle. You can create a sequence and then retrieve `nextval` from it just like i suggested

Comment: I mean i create the sequence before running the python script, and the oracle realized auto-increasing, there is no need to create sequence once more in python script.@mic4ael

Comment: Ok, I am not saying you should create it in your Python script.. What I am trying to tell you is that you should use it in your `INSERT` statement

Comment: you mean like this?
  
    for i in range((end-begin).days+1):
        print i
        day=begin+datetime.timedelta(days=i)
        a=(str(day),1,1,day.strftime("%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00"),1,day.strftime("%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00"),0)
        
        result.append(a)
   
    sql = "INSERT INTO factory_calendar (date,type,created_user,created_at,updated_user,updated_at,deleted) VALUES (seq_factory_calendar.nextval,:2, :3, :4, :5, :6, :7, :8)"
    cursor.prepare(sql)
    cursor.executemany(None,result)

Answer (score 0):

you mean like this?

```js
cursor = db.cursor()  # 使用cursor()方法获取操作游标

    begin=datetime.date(2017,1,1)
    end=datetime.date(2017,1,5)
    result=[]
    
    for i in range((end-begin).days+1):
        print i
        day=begin+datetime.timedelta(days=i)
        a=(str(day),1,1,day.strftime("%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00"),1,day.strftime("%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00"),0)
        print a
        result.append(a)
    
    print result
    sql = "INSERT INTO factory_calendar (date,type,created_user,created_at,updated_user,updated_at,deleted) VALUES (seq_factory_calendar.nextval,:2, :3, :4, :5, :6, :7, :8)"
    cursor.prepare(sql)
    cursor.executemany(None,result) #执行SQL语句
```

@mic4ael

Comment: `factory_calendar (id, date,type`